# RIA Service initialization problem

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism, wcf-ria-services

I have a problem with RIA services. Some times (not always) I get an InvalidOperationException with the message: "EntityTypes has already been initialized"

The error comes from the generated file but I don't know how to resolve this issue. Google brings out only 2 results which are not very helpfull.

Does anybody know what I could do to solve this or what I could try?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found now a solution.

After setting a breakpoint I noticed that I called two times the same method from different threads.

My theory: they accessed the same Domain Service query at the same time and this is for some reason not possible. This explains also because this error happens only sporadically.

Since I modified my code that this method is not called two times everything works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: After hours and hours of searching, this finally helped! I found that calling calling any domain service methods at the same time from multiple threads causes an error. It doesn't have to be the same domain service method.